# echo arguments to java program

Tags: java, linux, bash

I have a simple java program which counts arguments passed into it:

```
public class SubsetTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args.length);
    }
}
```

However in a bash shell I try to run the program as follows:

```
% echo A B C D | java SubsetTest
```

It always prints `0`. I expected `4`. What am I not doing right?

Comment: try this java SubsetTest A B C D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) is going to send the output of `echo` to the other process' standard input.

> a pipeline is the original software pipeline: a set of processes
>   chained by their standard streams, so that the output of each process
>   (stdout) feeds directly as input (stdin) to the next one

You can retrieve it with

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scanner.hasNext())
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
```

As for what you are trying to do, see [Redirecting stdout to program argument](https://superuser.com/questions/432084/redirecting-stdout-to-program-argument) or [Andreas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28523938/438154).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `xargs` to get the behaviour you want

```
echo A B C D | xargs java SubsetTest
```

Or you can try with back ticks

```
java SubsetTest `echo A B C D`
```

Comment: Don't use backticks: they are ugly and deprecated. Instead: `java SubsetTest $(echo A B C D)`, though this is a ticket to failure: you won't be able to pass arguments with spaces, newlines, or glob characters.

Comment: Sorry for not deliberating this in the question post. Subset takes one argument. These rest it expects from standard input. So ideally I'd want something like: `echo A B C D E F G G H | java Subset 3`. It would just print any 3 values echo-ed in...

Comment: Then @Sotirios has the correct answer, read from stdin using a Scanner.

Answer (score 0):

```
java SubsetTest <<< "A B C D"
```

Comment: answer edited..reason why i put echo is in the event the OP is considering shell variables

Comment: Your line is equivalent to OP's `echo A B C D | java SubsetTest`, yet with some bashism.